# Assembly decode for x64 JMP instruction

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, disassembly, machine-code

I am a very occasional user of assembly. So I need help from someone more expert to decode a small piece of code I have to deal with.

```
0000:  48 ff 25 61 57 07 00    rex.W jmp QWORD PTR [rip+0x75761]        # 0x75768
0007:  cc                      int3
```

This is a memory-indirect jump to an 8-byte/64-bit address held at `rip+0x75761`, so the absolute address the jump target is loaded from is `0007 + 0x75761` = `0x75768`, right?

Comment: Yes, by the way the REX.W is redundant.

Comment: Thanks ! Unfortunately the code is on a customer's x64 Windows 10 installation for one of the user32.dll functions. No idea how that code got there because it is not standard MS code. So I have to make accommodations for it.

Comment: Are you sure this is 64-bit machine code?  If it was disassembled as 32-bit code, the `0x48` byte would be a `dec` or `inc`.  (`dec eax` I think).

Comment: Yes, definitely 64 bit. The code was extracted from inside a 64 bit process. It is impossible for a 32 bit dll function to be callable from a 64 bit process. The user probably have some very old code that was overriding the API. It's one of those trampoline things.

Comment: @user118708 It is possible to call 32 bit code from a 64 bit process and vice versa, you have to do a far jump to change mode and then you can call the process. It's not officially supported but you can do it.

Comment: @FUZxxl I'd certainly would be very interested to know how with usable examples. The default calling convention for DLL functions is that the same bitness is enforced between the caller and callee. Since the DLL loading mechanism decides if it will load a DLL, I don't really have an option of loading a 32 DLL into a 64 bit process. For my purpose, 64 bits DLLs offer no advantage and I would be very happy to call 32 bit functions inside a 64 bit process if I have that choice.

Comment: @user118708 sure here you go: http://rce.co/knockin-on-heavens-gate-dynamic-processor-mode-switching/ , though you probably shouldn't actually do it.

Answer (score 3):

This is a standard tail-call sequence on x86-64, as would be generated by the Microsoft compiler.

Yes, as you said, it is an indirect jump to a 64-bit memory address, `0x75768`. At the point that this code is executed, `rip` is equal to 7, so `rip + 0x75761` == `0x7 + 0x75761` == `0x75768`. The code will unconditionally transfer control to the instructions at the address `0x75768`.

The subsequent `int 3` is just padding, but it also serves as a brick wall. Execution should never reach this point because of the unconditional branch in the previous instruction. If it did, the CPU would trap, since this is the "break" interrupt.

As for the REX.W prefix, harold is technically correct that it is unnecessary, but not for the reason you might think. Somewhat surprisingly, when an indirect jump through a register is used on x86-64, Windows requires the REX.W prefix in order to ensure that stack unwinding is successful. The stack unwinding code uses this as a signal internally. Ross Ridge has written [an excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36788685/meaning-of-rex-w-prefix-before-amd64-jmp-ff25) about the purpose of REX-prefixed JMP instructions in Windows x64.

It is not strictly necessary in this case because this is an indirect jump with an IP-relative operand, but the compiler is apparently emitting it anyway. Its logic for handling this is probably not that complex, and perhaps it always generates this code for consistency. Or maybe the official documentation is not comprehensive on exactly how the stack unwinding code is implemented. Better safe than sorry, since there's no real disadvantage in an extra REX.W prefix.

Comment: REX.W was added to the WIn32 API by Microsoft in their Windows 10 anniversary update. Even if optional, it is part of the OS going forward.

Comment: I don't think I understand what you're saying, @user. How do you add an assembly opcode to the API? If you're saying that the code shipped with Windows 10 uses this encoding, then yes, certainly it does. All versions of 64-bit Windows do and always have. No versions of 32-bit Windows do, including the 32-bit version of Windows 10 Anniversary Edition. And the reason it is "optional" here is because it is not actually necessary for IP-relative encodings. You only need it for indirect encodings. That hasn't changed in Windows 10. The stack unwinding still works the same way.

Comment: Hang on, it's not a relative jump.  It's using a RIP-relative addressing mode to load a 64-bit absolute pointer.  That's a lot different from `REX.W=1 jmp rel32` as a tailcall with no indirection.

Comment: Oh dear, am I totally wrong on the terminology here, @peter? Are you saying the fact that it's using an RIP-relative addressing mode is irrelevant, this is just a jump to immediate? That doesn't change the validity of the answer, because you don't need the REX.W prefix for `jmp QWORD PTR imm32` either, but I should probably fix the terminology if I'm using it wrong.

Comment: It would probably be more clear if you said "because this is an indirect jump with an IP-relative operand". Otherwise you seem to be suggesting it's a  a relative direct jump.

Comment: @CodyGray: I haven't looked at the details of the rules for when you do/don't need a REX.W, but this is an indirect jump.  For unwinding, just knowing the address + machine code of the function does not give you the destination; you have to know what that static storage location held when it was executed.  It might be true (IDK), but it's not obvious why PIC (RIP-relative) access to static data would be any different for unwinding purposes from any other memory or register addressing mode for the same opcode.

Comment: Right, that's what I thought. And I see the confusion now. The case where it's required is an indirect jump where the operand is a register. I had this in my head when I wrote "indirect jump", but didn't call it out explicitly. Peter and Ross are completely right that it is still an indirect jump when the operand is IP-relative. The difference is simply that, according to the documentation as I read it, REX.W is required in the former case but not in the latter. Updated the wording in the answer to reflect this, hopefully mitigating the confusion.

Comment: Thanks for checking on this.  Suggested wording: "because this is an indirect jump with a memory operand (not register), ...".  Your current wording unfortunately still makes it sound like the choice of addressing mode is relevant.  At this point, probably a good idea to link the docs you were looking at, since apparently it's complicated.

Comment: @Cody Gray, don't know about always have. I watched the code for a couple of years. Only at the anniversary update did the code unexpectedly changed that prompted my users jumping up and down saying my product  was broken. Hence the reason for posting the question.

Comment: How do we know that rip is 7? Why does the instruction register increment by 7 before executing the jump instruction at address 0?

Comment: @Theodore Ground rules of the x86 architecture. The instruction pointer always points to the instruction that will be executed next. So, when the CPU is in the process of executing the `JMP`, the instruction pointer (`RIP`) points to the *next* instruction, which in in this case is `INT 3`, so it contains the value 7.