# How to call a function through a function pointer passed as an argument?

Tags: assembly, function-pointers, x86-64, masm

How do I call passed function (*f2) in third argument of f1 function in assembly?
Declaration looks like that:

```
extern float f1(int v1, float v2, float (*f2)(int v3, float v4));
```

I want to pass v1 to v3, v2 to v4 , call function f2, and return value

```
f1:
    push rbp           
    mov rbp, rsp

    mov rdx, rdi ; v1 to v3
    mov xmm1, xmm0 ; v2 to v4
    call ??? 
    mov xmm0, xmm1

    mov rsp, rbp       
    pop rbp    
ret
```

what do I put in place of the question marks?

Comment: What is the application binary interface on the platform that you're on?  That will define where the parameters are and what the calling convention is.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer Abi64

Comment: what's that?  There's no such ABI.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no such thing as "Abi64". Since you tagged the question MASM, we can guess that you're using the Windows platform, and clearly the "64" means that this is 64-bit code, so that does narrow down the possibilities tremendously. However, there are still two common calling conventions for 64-bit code on Windows. One of them is `__vectorcall` and the other is the Microsoft x64 calling convention (the one that was originally invented to make all other calling conventions obsolete but…didn't).

Since the Microsoft x64 calling convention is the most common, and in this particular case, using `__vectorcall` wouldn't change anything, I'll assume it's the one that you're using. And then the code required becomes absolutely trivial. All you need to do is jump from `f1` to `f2`, since the stack will be set up identically. `f1`'s first two parameters are the two parameters that should be passed to `f2`, and the return value of `f2` is the return value of `f1`. Therefore:

```
f1:
    rex_jmp  r8    ; third parameter (pointer to f2) is passed in r8
```

This is not only trivial to write, but it is the most optimal implementation for both size and speed.
You can even modify the `v1` or `v2` parameters beforehand if you want, e.g.:

```
f1:
    inc      ecx        ; increment v1 (passed in ecx)

    ; multiply v2 (xmm1) by v1 (ecx)
    movd     xmm0, ecx
    cvtdq2ps xmm0, xmm0
    mulss    xmm1, xmm0

    rex_jmp  r8    ; third parameter (pointer to f2) is passed in r8
```

In case you wanted to do something more complicated, here's how it would work:

```
f1:
    sub   rsp, 40     ; allocate the required space on the stack
    call  r8          ; call f2 through the pointer, passed in r8
    add   rsp, 40     ; clean up the stack
    ret
```

Note that you do not need the prologue/epilogue code that you've shown in the question, though it won't hurt anything if you choose to include it.

However, the shuffling of parameters that you were doing in the example code shown in the question is *wrong*! In the Microsoft x64 calling convention, the first up-to-four integer arguments are passed in registers, from left to right, in RCX, RDX, R8, and R9. All other integer arguments are passed on the stack. The first up-to-four floating-point values are also passed in registers, from left to right, in XMM0, XMM1, XMM2, and XMM3. The rest are passed on the stack, along with structs too large for registers.

The weird thing, though, is that the slots are "fixed", so only 4 total register args can be used, even when you have a mix of integer and fp args.  Thus:

```
╔═══════════╦══════════════════════════╗
║           ║           TYPE           ║
║ PARAMETER ╠═════════╦════════════════╣
║           ║ Integer ║ Floating-Point ║
╠═══════════╬═════════╬════════════════╣
║ First     ║   RCX   ║      XMM0      ║
╠═══════════╬═════════╬════════════════╣
║ Second    ║   RDX   ║      XMM1      ║
╠═══════════╬═════════╬════════════════╣
║ Third     ║   R8    ║      XMM2      ║
╠═══════════╬═════════╬════════════════╣
║ Fourth    ║   R9    ║      XMM3      ║
╠═══════════╬═════════╩════════════════╣
║ (rest)    ║         on stack         ║
╚═══════════╩══════════════════════════╝
```

It doesn't matter that the second parameter is the first floating-point value that is being passed. It doesn't go in XMM0 because it's the first floating-point value, it goes in XMM1 because it's the second parameter and therefore in the second "slot".    (This is different from [the x86-64 System V ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#System_V_AMD64_ABI), where the first 6 integer args go in registers, whether or not there are FP args).

More detailed documentation on Windows parameter passing is available [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zthk2dkh.aspx), including examples.

Comment: *the most optimal implementation for both size and speed*: For size you'd use [CVTSI2SS](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/CVTSI2SS.html) and ignore the false dependency on the old value of XMM0 (thanks for the short-sighted design for PIII, Intel).  I was expecting what gcc does (`pxor xmm0, xmm0` / `cvtsi2ss xmm0, ecx`) to be optimal for speed, but it actually looks like MOVD and then a packed conversion might be the same lower latency and fewer total uops.  There might be a 1c bypass delay from MOVD to CVTDQ2PS.  (Agner lists it as 3+2c on Nehalem, so CVTDQ2PS wants float input there.)

Comment: Oops. I meant that comment to apply to the code above it, not necessarily my conversion of the floating-point value. I didn't write that for speed! Thanks for the info and the research, though! The code I've shown is essentially what MSVC will generate. Agner doesn't show later generations of processors as having that same penalty, so it probably is preferring to optimize for those as the most likely targets of a 64-bit build. Such would be my choice, at least. Although arguably GCC's code is more readable.

Comment: Why do you say `__fastcall` vs. "the Microsoft x64 calling convention"?  You seem to be saying that vectorcall and fastcall are (almost?) the same thing, and different from some other calling convention.  But I thought that x64 `__fastcall` was just a rarely-used term for the original Microsoft x64 calling convention that doesn't pass vectors in XMM / YMM regs.  (BTW, this [Intel tutorial guide for asm on Windows](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/introduction-to-x64-assembly) has a detailed description of the calling convention, and is all-around good.)

Comment: Well, I think we talked about this before, @Peter. I normally wouldn't use `__fastcall` at all with reference to 64-bit, but apparently Microsoft does, so I just wanted to make sure I mentioned it in case someone was looking at documentation that did. As best I can tell, it's used to refer to the new `__vectorcall` calling convention, but maybe that's not correct. I probably shouldn't have thrown it in. It just increases confusion. As for `__vectorcall`, it passes the first *six* parameters in registers and allows passing vectors in registers and thus by-value.

Comment: re: latency: later CPUs (SnB-family) have 1c bypass delays where they have them at all.  But Agner is not exactly consistent with his table formatting between updates.  He makes a bigger deal of domains for pre-SnB family, but there are still bypass delays for e.g. using BLENDPS between PADDD.  IDK which of MOVD + CVTDQ2PS vs. CVTSI2SS has a bypass delay, but it's not impossible.  The xor-zeroing is off the critical path, so gcc's method is rarely bad.

Comment: Yeah, we did talk about this before.  I'd forgotten that `__vectorcall` uses 6 integer arg-passing regs.  That's cool.  I'm almost certain that `__fastcall` is the original x64 convention.  The crappy one that passes vectors on the stack (which is the reason so many people write vector helper functions like `__m256 foo(__m256 &ref)` instead of passing by value, since I think MSVC even refuses to compile the by-value version for stack-alignment reasons, instead of just emitting code to align the stack for the non-inline case.)

Comment: Oh, `__vectorcall` uses up to 6 XMM regs, [but still only up-to-4 integer regs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn375768.aspx) :/

Comment: What's this `rex_jmp` mnemonic or macro in MASM?  [JMP r64](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/JMP.html) doesn't need a REX prefix for anything except access to R8-R15, so in NASM you'd just write `jmp r8`.

Comment: @peter I'm not sure if it's strictly necessary here, but tail called functions on x64 generally need a REX prefix on the JMP instruction, so that's the rule I always follow. See here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/freik/2009/02/09/quick-note-about-x64-tail-call/. Oh, and I see that Ross Ridge has already provided an excellent answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36788685/meaning-of-rex-w-prefix-before-amd64-jmp-ff25

Comment: Ahh, *How to emit a tail call through a register such that the OS unwinder doesn’t puke*.  So nothing to do with the code itself working.  Apparently a REX prefix on a JMP gives the stack-unwind code a clue that it's part of the epilogue.  I suppose that means you have to *avoid* r8-r15 for jump-table pointers inside the body of a function, though?  Sounds super-weird, and definitely worth mentioning as something you need to worry about if you're coding this by hand in asm as anything other than a learning-asm toy project.

Comment: @Peter The `REX` prefix in `rex_jmp` is encoded as `0100 1000` (48h), where the W field's bit is set (indicating a 64-bit operand size). By contrast, when you use `jmp` with R8-R15, the `REX` prefix is encoded as `0100 0001` (41h), where the B field's bit is set (indicating an extension of the MODRM.rm field). So I don't *think* there is a problem here with using R8-R15 for internal jump tables, since the stack unwinding code looks *specifically* for `48 FF` as the encoding. Hard to say for sure, though. I've never considered this, and the official documentation is rather vague.

Comment: Ok, yeah looking for REX.W=1 vs. REX.W=0 should work if that bit is always ignored by hardware.  Hopefully the unwinding code ignores other REX bits, so you can use something like `jmp [r8 + r9]` as a tail-call or as an internal jmp, and same for `jmp [rax + rcx]`.  (Besides REX.W, there's 1 bit each for base, index, and register (the /r part of modr/m))

Answer (score -2):

Assembly code differs based on the Micro controller in used.

Not exactly what you are looking for but following the assembly code generated by on Windows platform having intel core I7:-

C code:-

```
extern float f1(int v1, float v2, float (*f2)(int v3, float v4))
{
    float a = 10.0;
    int b = 12;

    f2(b, a);
    return a+ 12.5;
}
```

Assembly code:-

```
_f1:
 pushl  %ebp
 movl   %esp, %ebp
 subl   $40, %esp
 movl   LC0, %eax

 movl   %eax, -12(%ebp)
 movl   $12, -16(%ebp)
 movl   -12(%ebp), %eax
 movl   %eax, 4(%esp)
 movl   -16(%ebp), %eax
 movl   %eax, (%esp)
 movl   16(%ebp), %eax
 call   *%eax
 fstp   %st(0)
 flds   -12(%ebp)
 flds   LC1
 faddp  %st, %st(1)
 leave
ret
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Evidently, you compiled this code without optimizations enabled, which is a bad idea, because it gives you a lot of irrelevant noise. You also apparently compiled it on a compiler that does *not* use Microsoft's x64 calling convention, which would make it confusing and unhelpful to the person who asked the question. Granted, the question was underspecified, but it's certainly clear that he's using MASM and targeting x64. This isn't MASM syntax, and no x64 calling convention on Windows ever passes the first four integer or floating-point parameters on the stack.